# How do governments carry out computer surveillance?

Tags: privacy, sniffer

If HTTPS is really secure as companies tell us, how do governments manage to eavesdrop on terrorist and criminal communications?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_and_network_surveillance

Comment: a terrorist for sure know what is http and https. if https is secure so why they capture all internet traffic ?!

Comment: Who says all terrorists are careful? Who says they do not have access to some of those private keys? Who says they are not using virusses?

Comment: For email they can cooperate with your email provider. I'd expect gmail etc. to cooperate with some governments.

Comment: http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2012/03/ff_nsadatacenter/ -- but I still think it [depends on your level of paranoia](http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2012/03/28/nsa-dismisses-claims-utah-data-center-watches-average-americans/)

Comment: You realise that no government can sniff everything, right? Even if everything was in http only it wouldn't be possible. I have edited to remove some of the unfounded paranoia.

Comment: Well said Rory. They capture lot's of traffic, but it doesnt mean they can actually read it.

Answer (score 6):

Governments [purchase spyware from private companies](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2011/12/gallery-how-the-surveillance-industry-markets-spyware-to-governments/).

[image]

Some companies like [VUPEN](http://www.vupen.com) are known for building [complex 0-day exploits against browsers](http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2012/03/how-to-pwn-the-pwn2own-contest/) and selling them privately to anyone for hundreds of thousands of dollars.

Recently the Obama Administration has [moved to block the sale of such technology](http://www.infoworld.com/d/security/obama-takes-steps-block-sale-of-surveillance-tech-syria-iran-191517) to Iran and Syria.  Iran is known to be [performing active MITM attacks against gmail](http://news.cnet.com/8301-27080_3-20099421-245/google-users-in-iran-targeted-in-ssl-spoof/).

Comment: what wikipedia says is they sniff all the internet traffic to see for example when someone say "bomb" to catch him. question is we all use https ... what is that mean !

Comment: @John - don't believe everything you read on the internet...

Answer (score 3):

There are ways like:

- spoofing the SSL certificate
- compromise endpoint or beginpoint (rootkits)
- guess the user's password
- ...

Comment: so we always see a fake SSL on browser that shining green ?

Comment: No, if they are spoofed then not. But it has happened that certificates were stolen (Iran). So then you have a MITM attack that actually validates.

Comment: seems usa capture all internet traffic. something is wrong

Comment: @John do you have basic understanding of how SSL works? Also do you have any IT background because I feel that you just discovered this and feel like you need to go after the government or something...

Answer (score 3):

The US government is known to use keyloggers, don't know if they're physical widgets in-line with the keyboard, or software. [Nicodemo Scarfo, Jr](http://articles.latimes.com/keyword/nicodemo-scarfo) was apparently convicted using some kind of keylogger data.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I actually cited a US Federal case that the FBI had to reveal that they used keyloggers.  At least have the brass to say why you're downvoting, coward.

Answer (score -2):

So how it works, they collect lot's of information, filter it, database it, trace you and listen to your phone, email and everything else at the same time. This gives a complete picture, so when you are using SSL, this is just a small piece which doesnt change much :-)

Also, they have the most important information, no matter how strong encryption you got - who are you talking with.

ps. When you are using SSL to buy something, maybe they cant see it, but they can see your CC payment.

ps2. Total obfuscation is not possible, even a policy with good enforcement is not enough, they can see who is sending, they can trace who is supposed to receive.

Simply you can run, but you cant hide.

Comment: SSL is encrypted traffic which means without the encryption key it would be useless noise.  Your answer doesn't offer any FACTS.

Comment: Noise signals communication, and this way attack can be launched on either of the side of the encryption and decryption, so with SSL you cant guarantee confidence for 100%.

Comment: Why do you think that SSL can't guarantee confidence?